# Why can't I change the zIndex here?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a bunch of divs positioned on top of an image.
I am trying to make the fraction hidden by the div to appear on the mouse hover. To achieve this I tried setting the zIndex of the div to be lower than the one of the image so it gets revealed. But I can seem to select ALL the divs.

Here is my javascript code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var block = document.getElementById('container');

    block.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        var blocks = document.querySelectorAll("#container div");
        var index = 0, length = blocks.length;
        for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            blocks[index].style.zIndex = 2;
        }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "block";
            div.style.left = j * 25 + 'px';
            div.style.top = i * 25 + 'px';
            div.style.display = "inline-block";
            div.style.verticalAlign = "top";
            div.style.zIndex = "1";
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
        }
        var jump = document.createElement("br");
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump);
    }
};
```

Where did I go wrong? Thank you. The div container has the background image that is placed "under" the created inner divs.

Comment: Probably because `Array` has no property `style`.

Comment: Also please bear in mind that the elements need to be positioned absolutely for the `z-index` to work at all (huh - thanks to @j08691 for pointing this out - keeping my original comment though)

Comment: `mousehover` event does not exist. `mouseover` is the right one.

Comment: @eithedog - No, that's incorrect. They just need to be positioned (i.e. non-static).

Comment: The other thing is that if the image is itself in a div, this won't work.

Comment: @Sebas the image is the div's background. How can I solved this?

Comment: @j08691 I keep on confusing, thanks !

Comment: @Predator44, sorry, I mislead you. If it's in a div that is in #container, then it won't work (because you would then change the zIndex of a parent of the image) But if it's in its own div and you don't touch its zIndex, then you're good.

Comment: @Sebas Ah okay! what if the div has the background img? What should I do then?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's not clear to me how your layering is setup. The thing you have to keep in mind is that when you change the zIndex of a given div, everything contained in it (recursively!) cannot appear behind.

Answer (score 1):

document.querySelectorAll returns an array of elements. You would need to loop through them individually.

```
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll("#container div");
var index = 0, length = blocks.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    blocks[index].style.zIndex = 1;
}
```

If you are only looking for a single element you can also use document.querySelector which returns the first element it finds that matches the selector and you can work directly on it as you originally had in your code.

Comment: I added further explanation in my question. Thanks for the help